# Flink sql writes no data to es cluster?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-flink, flink-sql

*Problem description:* I want to query the data in my mysql or hive through sql and write it to my es cluster. The program can run successfully but es has no data

1. *Software version:*

- flink: 1.11
- es: 6.2.2
- hive: 1.2.1
- mysql: 5.7

2. *Below is my code*

```java
public class HiveExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatabaseNotExistException {
        EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance()
                .useBlinkPlanner()
                .inBatchMode()
                .build();
        TableEnvironment tabEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);


        String sql =
                "insert into user_action_es_sink " +
                        "select 100123,5,11,1,'a','b','111','bbb',cast(11111 as bigint),cast('2020-11-11' as date) from dragonfly.web_page limit 10" ;


        String sporeUserAuthCreateTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE users (\n" +
                "  `id` INT,\n" +
                "  `userid` INT,\n" +
                "  `type` INT,\n" +
                "   PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED" +
                ") WITH (\n" +
                "  'connector' = 'jdbc',\n" +
                "  'url' = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spore',\n" +
                "  'table-name' = 'spore_user_auth',\n" +
                "  'driver' = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',\n" +
                "  'username' = 'xxxx',\n" +
                "  'password'  = 'xxxx'\n" +
                ")";

        tabEnv.executeSql(sporeUserAuthCreateTableSQL);

        String esTable = "CREATE TABLE user_action_es_sink (\n" +
                "  uid INT,\n" +
                "  appid INT,\n" +
                "  prepage_id INT,\n" +
                "  page_id INT,\n" +
                "  action_id STRING,\n" +
                "  page_name STRING,\n" +
                "  action_name STRING,\n" +
                "  prepage_name STRING,\n" +
                "  stat_time BIGINT,\n" +
                "  dt DATE\n" +
//                "  PRIMARY KEY (uid,dt) NOT ENFORCED\n" +
                ") WITH (\n" +
                "  'connector' = 'elasticsearch-6',\n" +
                "  'hosts' = 'http://localhost:9200',\n" +
                "  'index' = 'mytest',\n" +
                "  'document-type' = 'user_action'\n" +
//                "  'sink.bulk-flush.max-size' = '0',\n" +
//                "  'sink.bulk-flush.max-actions' = '0',\n" +
//                "  'sink.bulk-flush.interval' = '0'\n"+
//                "  'format' = 'json',\n" +
//                "  'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',\n"+
//                "  'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true'\n" +
                ")";

        tabEnv.executeSql(esTable);

        tabEnv.executeSql("insert into user_action_es_sink select 100123,5,11,1,'a','b','111','bbb',cast(11111 as bigint),cast('2020-11-11' as date) from users limit 10").print();


    }
}
```

*My pom file :*

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner-blink_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>${hive.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-jdbc_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-orc-nohive_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch6_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-elasticsearch6_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-json</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The code did not prompt me any abnormal information, but the data was not written, and it is not clear what caused the problem.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The `executeSql` function works in async node, if you're testing in your IDE，the main function will exit after called `executeSql` function and the underlying mini-cluster will shutdown after the main function finished. This only exists in local test, the production cluster is always alive and the submitted job will execute normally.

If you want to wait the job execution in IDE, you can use following method.

```
tabEnv.executeSql("insert into user_action_es_sink select xxx ")
      .getJobClient().get()          
      .getJobExecutionResult(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).get();
```

And in Flink 1.12, there's a simple way to do this:

```
tabEnv.executeSql("insert into user_action_es_sink select xxx ")
      .await();
```